# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()

Tags: php, ini

venho recebendo este erro e não sei como solucioná-lo. Não uso o xampp em minha máquina e abaixo, é possível observar meu arquivo de configuração do php. Alguém pode me ajudar ?

[image: Php Config]

Comment: Verifique se a extensão `mysqli.so` ou `mysqli.dll` está habilitada no `php.ini` e instalada em seu servidor. Caso não esteja basta utilizar `sudo apt-get install php-mysqli` e adicionar `extension=mysqli.so` (Linux) ou `extension=mysqli.dll` (Windows)

Comment: extension=mysqli.dll no cmd do Windows ?

Comment: Não, no arquivo `php.ini`.

Comment: no php 7.0, existem dois tipos de php.ini. O php.ini-development e o php.ini-production. Devo fazer nos dois ?

Comment: Procura na imagem o valor de "Loaded Configuration File", é nesse arquivo que você deve editar.

Comment: Continua acusando o mesmo erro. Removi o ; em frente ao nome do extension=php_mysqli.dll

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72443/discussion-between-valdeir-psr-and-alexsander-caproni).